# Why don't I get my bash customizations when I log in normally?

Tags: bash, prompt, bashrc

My user's shell prompt is stuck as

```
[bash-4.2]$
```

and many useful commands like `ll` don't work on that bash-4.2 shell.

I tried the `chsh` command and `usermod` commands, but neither fixed this.

I've checked in the `/etc/passwd` file, the shell associated with my user is `/bin/bash`. The other users too have the same lines but those users are presented with the normal bash prompt:

```
[vin@localhost ~]$
```

My `~/.bash_profile` is

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

I've noticed that when I log into my user `vin` through the root or an another account that has the normal bash, it stays on that bash type, doesn't get back to the broken bash.

What could be wrong? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you messed with your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile files?

Comment: What do you want the shell to be?

Comment: @steeldriver no, I haven't, as far as I remember.

Comment: @DavidKing I want it look like the usual [user@localhost ~]$ . Currently it looks like "bash-4.2$" on which many useful commands don't work.

Comment: `ll` isn't a command, it's a *shell alias* to run the `ls` command with certain options. The appearance of the prompt (whether it's `bash-4.2` or `vin@localhost`) isn't really indicative of anything except the setting of the PS1 variable. Both these things are likely determined by the contents of your `~/.bashrc` file: that's where you should start to look for what could be wrong.

Comment: Can you provide the contents of your bash_profile file?

Comment: here's the content of my bash_profile file
http://pastebin.com/SHYx9AZ3
 I've noticed that when I log into my user vin through the root or an another account that has the normal bash, it stays on that bash type, doesn't get back to the broken bash.

Comment: If you run `bash` again from the `[bash-4.2]$` prompt, which prompt do you get? What if you run `bash -l`? What is the output of `ls -ld ~/.bash*` ?

Comment: there are 4 files - .bash_history  .bash_logout  .bash_profile  .bashrc
- similar to all other users. I replaced the files by other user's, but no change at all. I'm gonna delete this broken bash prompt user and create a new one. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This: `[bash-4.2]$` is called the "shell prompt", not the "shell name".

The shell prompt in Bash is stored in an ordinary shell variable called `PS1`. The contents of `PS1` is a prompt format string which consists of a mixture of ordinary text, plus special codes like `\h` to insert the host name, `\w` to insert the working directory or `\$` to insert the character `#` if the user is `root` or `$` otherwise. For instance:

```
PS1='\h:\w\$ '
```

Now your prompt looks like:

```
machinename:/path/to/where/you/are$ _
```

The underscore represents the cursor.  According to the man page for recent versions of Bash, the default value of PS1 is `\s-\v\$`, which produces the shell name, a literal dash, the shell version and a prompt not followed by a space: exactly what you're seeing.

Read the Bash man page, and skip to the section `PROMPTING` to read all about this topic.

The other users have a nicer prompt because of some configuration difference between your account and theirs. You might be missing some configuration files like `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc`, or `PS1` is not configured in these files. Perhaps your account doesn't have a correct home directory at all.

The `chsh` command changes your login shell entirely, as in using a different program. This is the tool to use if you don't want to use Bash at all, but something else like Zsh or Tcsh. It will not take place in the calling session; it affects a new login session.

Comment: When I set the value of PS1, the bash prompt (thanks for telling me about the proper term) changes but it's temporary. When I launch the terminal again, it goes back to bash-4.2 .
I added the PS1's value to bashrc file, it seems that some other settings are overriding the bashrc content, because this works well with other users.